# The record is inserting multiple times. How to avoid recurssion?

Tags: code

Using apex class I am inserting records into the Opportunity Line items. Here I am inserting from the custom object.  Based on the family I am inserting only one record per family in the Opportunity line item.
The issue is if custom object has 4 records with  then when inserted the record count is 8. 
Part of code :

```
   List<CustomObject__c> cbList = [Select Id, Name, Product_Family__c from CustomObject__c where Opp__c=:opId];

for(CustomObject__c cbs: cbList){
    for (String productFamily : PMap.keySet()){

        pricebookE=[SELECT Id, Product2.Name,UnitPrice, Pricebook2Id, Name, Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry
        WHERE Pricebook2Id=: PriceBook2ID.Id
        AND (Product2.Name =:productFamily) AND IsActive = true];


            for(Pricebookentry p: pricebookE){
                OpportunityLineItem ol=new OpportunityLineItem();
                ol.PriceBookEntryId=p.Id;
                ol.Opportunityid=cbs.Opportunity__r.id;
                ol.Quantity=1;
                ol.UnitPrice=PMap.get(name);
                oplist.add(ol);

            }
        }


    }
    insert oplist;
```

Comment: What is the expected count for the OpportunityLineItem records? You might need to add a `continue` if the CustomObject__c.Name__c is already in PMap to prevent additional OLIs being added to `oplist`.

Answer (score -2):

Write a Static Class, with a boolean variable to keep check on recursion. So that the code is executed only one time.and not in the loop.